# View is not displaying after pushing on navigationController stack

Tags: ios5, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I am trying to use a navigation controller to push/pop views, but I don't want the bar at the top with the buttons; I'm doing the navigation UI myself.

So I created a navigationController in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[WSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                      initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

and then in my WSViewController, I have an IBAction method that pushes another view on the navigation stack (I've verified that it's doing this correctly; I see it on the stack):

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.wsInfoViewController == nil) {
        WSInfoViewController *wic = [[WSInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.wsInfoViewController = wic;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.wsInfoViewController animated:YES];
}
```

But I'm not seeing the info view show up when I tap on the info button in my WSViewController (which is showing up just fine).

If I make the navigationController the root controller, then I *do* see the wsInfoViewController when I tap on the info button, however, I also get the navigation bar at the top, which I don't want!

So... first, am I wrong in thinking I can use a navigation controller this way (i.e. using it for stack purposes but not for any UI at all)?

Second, if I'm not wrong, why isn't the view I'm pushing onto the stack showing up? I'm guessing it's because I'm not hooking the navigation controller up to the window correctly, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks!!!

Elisabeth

Comment: you connect IBOutlet with your viewController?

Comment: You mean is my showInfo method getting called when I tap on the button? yes, and I've put a break point just after where I push the view on the stack, and the view is definitely on the stack. I think the issue is that the window isn't aware of the navigationController stack, but I don't know how to set that up properly.

Comment: No. I mean are you connected your IBOutlet WSInfoViewController with your viewController in FileOwner?

Comment: I'm not sure why I need an IBOutlet. I'm creating WSInfoViewController myself in the showInfo: method, and stashing a reference in a property in a property in my WSViewController. Isn't that basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have the answer to my question. Which is, you must set up the navigation controller as the root view controller for the AppDelegate window in order to use it, otherwise, the window doesn't know about it.  My WSViewController is still the root view controller for the navigation controller. And then to get rid of the navigation bar, you can hide it.
Here's the updated code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[WSViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSViewController" bundle:nil];
    // doesn't work!
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                      initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    // do this instead
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

To hide the nav bar in the views, in each view where you want it hidden, add the following methods:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```

This is working great so far!